# Upload image does not work in Android app but working in Postman Plugin in Codeigniter

Tags: php, android, api, codeigniter-3

I face the problem like as follow:

I develop API in codeigniter for upload image into specific folder of server. When i check in postman that works fine. But, when i check with android app that does not work fine.

Please give me suggestion.

Thanks in advance.

My code as below:

```
public function updateimage_post() {
    if(!$this->post('UserID')) {
        $status = [
            ['status' => 400 ,  'message' => 'UserID is required.'],
        ];
        $this->response($status, REST_Controller::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST);
    } else {
        $this->db->where(array('ID' => $this->post('UserID')));
        $db_result = $this->db->get('userregistration');

        if ($db_result && $db_result->num_rows() > 0) {
            if(isset($_FILES['ProfilePicture']['name'])) {
                $info = pathinfo($_FILES['ProfilePicture']['name']);
                $ext = $info['extension'];
                if (($ext == "GIF" || $ext == "PNG" || $ext == "JPG" || $ext == "jpg" || $ext == 'gif' || $ext == 'png' || $ext == 'jpeg') && ($_FILES["ProfilePicture"]["type"] == "image/PNG" || $_FILES["ProfilePicture"]["type"] == "image/GIF" || $_FILES["ProfilePicture"]["type"] == "image/JPG" || $_FILES["ProfilePicture"]["type"] == "image/jpg" ||$_FILES["ProfilePicture"]["type"] == "image/jpeg" || $_FILES["ProfilePicture"]["type"] == 'image/gif' || $_FILES["ProfilePicture"]["type"] == 'image/png') && ($_FILES["ProfilePicture"]["size"] < 30485760)) {
                    $file = $info['filename'];
                    $filename = 'frontuser' . '_' . uniqid() . '.' . $ext;
                    $target = './uploads/frontusers/' . $filename;
                    $file = $_FILES['ProfilePicture']['tmp_name'];
                    if (move_uploaded_file($file, $target)) {
                        $data = array(
                            'ProfilePicture' => $filename,
                            'ModifiedOn' => date('Y-m-d H:m:s'),
                        );
                        $result = $this->db->update('userregistration', $data, array('ID' => $this->post('UserID')));
                    } else {
                        $status = ['status' => 201 ,  'message' => 'Image not uploaded.'];
                        $this->response($status, REST_Controller::HTTP_OK);
                    }
                } else {
                    $status = ['status' => 201 ,  'message' => 'File is invalid.'];
                    $this->response($status, REST_Controller::HTTP_OK);
                }
            } else {
                $status = ['status' => 201 ,  'message' => 'Please Select image.'];
                $this->response($status, REST_Controller::HTTP_OK);
            }

            if($result) {
                $status = [
                    'status' => 200,
                    'message' => 'Profile Picture Update Successfully',
                    ];
            } else {
                $status = [
                    'status' => 201,
                    'message' => 'Something went wrong !!',
                    ];
            }
            $this->set_response($status, REST_Controller::HTTP_OK);
        } else {
            $status = [
                    'status' => 201,
                    'message' => 'UserID does not exist !!',
                    ];
            $this->set_response($status, REST_Controller::HTTP_OK);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: is it related to android?

Comment: yes it only does not work in android app

Comment: When update image from android app that time call this codeigniter api @android_griezmann

Comment: is you app native file upload or something in the webview. the latter usually not works well

Comment: so how can i solve this ? @KrisRoofe

Comment: you mean you file input is in the webview???

Comment: In postman plugin we can check api work or not !!
In that i check it works fine but does not work in android app

Comment: can you show the upload code,considering postman is working fine that would mean the backend code is correct so there must be something wrong with the android code.]